# Community user bumping a post but no banner on mobile

Tags: bug, mobile-web, community-user, bump

I just saw this post on the homepage: [Using IF condition to copy either one cell or another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046230/using-if-condition-to-copy-either-one-cell-or-another) where community made a change to it one hour ago. As you can see there was no edit made by the community user on neither the question nor any of its answers. As all answers have zero score, I believe it was bumped to review the answers. On the desktop site, you see a banner stating the same but it is missing from the mobile site. Making my browser request the desktop version makes the banner appear.

Comment: It's a shame that the community user didn't simply send a comment to [user2474838](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2474838/user2474838) (who hasn't been seen here since 2013) and leave the question alone.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, well that indeed is a shame, but also a different topic. If you feel strong enough about this I'd suggest you to write a feature request.

Comment: Community really loves bumping that question...